# Replace script without losing localized script

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

A script in a plugin is conflicting with my theme so I want to replace it with my themes modified version.

The problem I am having is that when I remove it like:

```
wp_deregister_script( 'script-name' );
```

Then it also removes the script localization.

```
wp_localize_script( 'script-name', 'local_name', $vars );
```

The localized script has all the data generated from the plugin so would be a lot of work for me to re-create all of this so instead of completely de-registering "script-name" I just want to change its path to point to my script without loosing the localize script.

All methods I find involve removing "script-name" and as soon as I do that I lose the localize script.

Is there a different approach I can take or is this not possible and I just have to re-create this script myself?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with the $wp_scripts class.  I just updated the src like this:

```
global $wp_scripts;

$wp_scripts->registered['script-name']->src = 'my/path/to/file.js';
```